# No JREs installed in the work space that are strictly compatible with this environment

Tags: java, eclipse

The following warning i am getting after running my java project in eclipse.

```
**Description Resource Path Location Type Build path specifies execution environment CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1. There are no JREs installed in the work space that are strictly compatible with this environment**.
```

Comment: So is your Java a J2ME Foundation Profile project - which is what CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1 specifies?

Comment: no its a simple java application(J2SE). @greg-449

Answer (score 22):

Open the Properties for the project and select `Java Build Path`, look at the `Libraries` tab.
Select the `JRE System Library` entry and click the `Edit...` button. Choose a more sensible Execution environment or JRE from the list in the Edit Library dialog.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just edited the java version of pom.xml and it worked fine

Before:

```
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>
```

After:

```
  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>
```

Comment: Consider setting it to either 13 or 15 for newer versions of java.