# Eclipse IDE - Error: Build path specifies execution environment Java SE 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling

In Eclipse, I am getting an error:

> Build path specifies execution environment Java SE 1.7. 
>   There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No JREs installed in the work space that are strictly compatible with this environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135863/no-jres-installed-in-the-work-space-that-are-strictly-compatible-with-this-envir)

Comment: Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Add...

Answer (score 66):

Try this

```
 In Eclipse,
your project
-> properties
-> java build path : Libraries
Remove the "JRE System Library[J2SE 1.4]"
-> click "Add Library" button -> JRE System Library
-> select the new "Executin Environment" or Workspace default JRE
```

Comment: How to resolve the same error in vscode?

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

- Your project > Build Path > Configure Build Path.
- Go to Libraries tab.
- Select JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.7].
- Press Edit.
- Notice that "Execution environment" is JavaSE-1.7 (jdk1.8.{y}).
- Click on Installed JREs.
- You should see jdk1.8.{y} but not jdk1.7.{x}.
- Press Add.
- Select Standard VM.
- Press Next.
- Locate your java folder, e.g.:
  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.{x}`.
  If you don't have it, you need to install it.
- Populate JRE home with it. e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80`.

"Execution environment" will be JavaSE-1.7 (jdk1.7.0_80) now.

Answer (score 8):

Go to Project|Properties
Choose the Java Build Path section
Select the current JRE System Library, and choose Remove
Select Add Library, and under the JRE System Library category pick your system library; you probably just need to choose the Workspace default JRE

More generally, under Window|Preferences, you can check Java|Installed JREs|Execution Environments to know which of the installed JREs match a specific execution environment.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like what I had after installing a newer Eclipse.

My solution:

Window->Preferences,
Java->Installed JREs->Execution Environment.

Click the correct environment in the left panel, probably JavaSE-jre7

If the checkbox in the right panel is empty, check it.

If it's checked, but it isn't named **jre7 [perfect match]** then find the one in the left panel that does have 'perfect match' on the right and check that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have this situation because I have multiple JDKs, and the JREs are nested below them. I'm building a JRE8 project but my current default is the latest v11. So the challenge is to get Eclipse to recognize the JDK>JREv8.

1. Go to Preferences > Java > Installed JREs.
2. Click Add.
3. Navigate to the JRE under the JDK, which in my case is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre.
4. Change the JRE name to JDK8 JRE8 just for clarity.
5. Click Finish.

On build the error goes away. :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved by

```
Right click on JRE System Library
Select Properties
Choose Workplace Default JRE
Apply and Close
```

Comment: It was that simple

Answer (score 0):

Go To Control Panel 
- check whether any new java version Updated 
-Uninstall it and Configure the Build Path JRE Library "Execution environment" to the Previous Version.

Probably if Java 7 is updated to Java 8 the above problem will occur. To avoid that warning, just you can uninstall the new update and restore the old version in execution environment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open eclipse
2. Right click on your project -> click "properties"
3. Select "Java Build Path" and then choose Librarires
4. Delete JRE System Library [jre1.*.*_***]
5. Click "Add Library" and then choose "JRE System Library"
6. The best solution is to mark "Workspace default JRE (jre1.*,*_***)
7. Refresh project and wait for Tomcat or any other additional server to restart and then should be no error for "Execution environment.."[Where to do it!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6k9T.png)

Comment: What is your output of 'java -version- in cmd?

Answer (score 0):

**Exact Solution**
Right click on your project

1. Properties
2. Java Build Path --> Libraries and
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OsSr.png)
3. Modulepath --> Add Library
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvGjF.png)
4. JRE System Library, next> choose "Workspace default JRE"
   AND finish. Solved!

Answer (score 0):

<< If you're using Gradle >>

set gradle java-home in windows>preferences.
And see project's config.
so Gradle won't use eclipse default jvm and let you work with another jre.

Answer (score 0):

If the above solutions don't solve your problem try using the latest Eclipse version.

Surely this will solve your problem.

I was using the older version i.e., Eclipse version 2020-03 which is not at all compatible with Java-17.