# Another "Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-13." problem

Tags: java, eclipse

So, the full warning looks like
`Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-13. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.`
I just installed JDK(version: 14.0.1 from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html)) and Eclipse(Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0) from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/2020-03/R/eclipse-inst-win64.exe))
I've read [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345131/eclipse-ide-error-build-path-specifies-execution-environment-java-se-1-7/26345372) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135863/no-jres-installed-in-the-work-space-that-are-strictly-compatible-with-this-envir?noredirect=1&lq=1) but i dont have any libraries in Java->Build Path -> User libraries. It's empty at all. In Installed Libraries i don't have any jdk{version}. I only have Name "JDK" and Location "D:\..."
Am i missing something vital? Because i have no idea how to fix it.
I am newbee, so if you have an answer or following question, please write a bit simpler. Thank you.

Comment: You have to configure the JRE/JDK in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_, so they can be used in the Java Build Path and in run configurations.

Answer (score 0):

This should really be a comment, but I felt like spelling things out. The main thing to watch out for here is that with Java its version comes into play at least 4 times and there is nothing strictly stopping you from having 4 different versions configured on each occasion, which may or may not work. Add Eclipse and it becomes at least 5:

1. The java binary used to run Eclipse itself. (Configured via eclipse.ini)

   - This can affect how plugins behave. I remember a scenario where `m2e` would refuse to use a Java compliance level older than the version of the JRE running Eclipse. I can't make too confident specific calls from the top of my head here, but this is something to keep in mind.
   - Should be latest and greatest, though Java 8 appears to be the defensive option for obscure scenarios, such as projects depending on deprecated internal libraries. (`tools.jar` comes to mind)
2. The javac (java compiler) binary used to build your project. (Sits next to the java binary in a `bin` subdirectory of the JDK)

   - Should also be latest and greatest: every version of javac is capable of compiling source code written for previous versions as well as generating compatible byte code for older versions. This is what the following two points are about.
3. The Java version that javac is told to assert that your code is compatible with. (javac `-source` parameter)
4. The Java version that javac is told to make your build compatible with. (javac `-target` parameter; equal or greater than the value of `-source`)
5. The java  binary used to run your build.

   - Should also be latest and greatest, though the minimum version required here is what was given to javac via `-target`, and incompatibility scenarios do exist.
   - The latest trend here is to ship every Java application with its own JRE to rule out problems arising from users having configured or installed Java in an incompatible manner. A user will then be required run a specially crafted native executable or a shortcut which will then invoke Java with the right arguments to start the application.

Now, you do not invoke javac or java even. In fact, the former is not even invoked by Eclipse. Eclipse actually comes with its own Java compiler, [Eclipse Compiler for Java (ECJ)](https://www.codejava.net/ides/eclipse/why-does-eclipse-use-its-own-java-compiler). For what it's worth, we don't usually need to worry about that however. For Eclipse to know anything about available JREs, you need to match JDK locations on disk to Java versions "known" to Eclipse. This is done under `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Execution Environments`.

After doing that, they should pop up in all the places where you can specify Java versions, which is mainly Project settings and possibly run configurations you have set up or Eclipse has set up for you. Project settings can then be set to up to infer the compliance level for building from the version of the JRE configured to run the build.

By the way, note that you probably want to use AdoptOpenJDK instead of the release from Oracle for [reasons](https://upperedge.com/oracle/top-3-reasons-oracle-java-users-are-unknowingly-out-of-compliance/). You'll also want to just unpack any JREs which aren't the latest one in a nice folder somewhere on your hard drive instead of installing them. Installing them mostly means to make `.jar` files run with that version when launched from your OS's file browser. If you are on Linux, `sdkman` is currently the preferred way to do this.

Comment: Your comment answer is based on a number of false facts. Eclipse has its own compiler and m2e runs like a charm (in case this matters here; Maven might not used at all), to name just two.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I forgot about ECJ. I'll change that. Regarding m2e: you're right, what I remembered was actually just an unexpected behavior. We got haunted by an equivalent of https://github.com/javadelight/delight-nashorn-sandbox/issues/62 once because m2e will never use a Java version compliance level older than the version of the JRE running Eclipse itself when building. Hence why I called Java 8 being a "defensive" choice for running Eclipse itself.