# There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am new to code. I am getting this error while executing the script on Selenium webdriver. Does anybody know how can I run my scripts. I tried using all the three options under configure build path but it doesn't work. Can anybody help me?

I am getting this error:

```
Build path specifies execution environment CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment
```

Comment: Is your project *supposed to be* a J2ME project?

Comment: If not ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135863/no-jres-installed-in-the-work-space-that-are-strictly-compatible-with-this-envir